# How to pass files found by find as arguments?

Tags: bash, command-line, find, arguments

First to cut off trivial but inapplicable answers: I can use neither the `find`+`xargs` trick nor its variants (like `find` with `-exec`) because I need to use few such expressions per call. I will get back to this at the end.

---

Now for a better example let's consider:

```
$ find -L some/dir -name \*.abc | sort
some/dir/1.abc
some/dir/2.abc
some/dir/a space.abc
```

How do I pass those as arguments to `program`?

## Just doing it doesn't do the trick

```
$ ./program $(find -L some/dir -name \*.abc | sort)
```

fails since `program` gets following arguments:

```
[0]: ./program
[1]: some/dir/1.abc
[2]: some/dir/2.abc
[3]: some/dir/a
[4]: space.abc
```

As can be seen, the path with space was split and `program` considers it to be two different arguments.

## Quote until it works

It seems novice users such as myself, when faced with such problems, tend to randomly add quotes until it finally works - only here it doesn't seem to help…

### `"$(…)"`

```
$ ./program "$(find -L some/dir -name \*.abc | sort)"
[0]: ./program
[1]: some/dir/1.abc
some/dir/2.abc
some/dir/a space.abc
```

Because the quotes prevent word-splitting, all the files are passed as a single argument.

### Quoting individual paths

A promising approach:

```
$ ./program $(find -L some/dir -name \*.abc -printf '"%p"\n' | sort)
[1]: "some/dir/1.abc"
[2]: "some/dir/2.abc"
[3]: "some/dir/a
[4]: space.abc"
```

The quotes are there, sure. But they are no longer interpreted. They are just part of the strings. So not only they did not prevent word splitting, but also they got into arguments!

## Change IFS

Then I tried playing around with `IFS`. I would prefer `find` with `-print0` and `sort` with `-z` anyway - so that they will have no issues on "wired paths" themselves. So why not force word splitting on the `null` character and have it all?

```
$ ./program $(IFS=$'\0' find -L some/dir -name \*.abc -print0 | sort -z)
[0]: ./program
[1]: some/dir/1.abcsome/dir/2.abcsome/dir/a
[2]: space.abc
```

So it still splits on space and does not split on the `null`.

I tried to place the `IFS` assignment both in `$(…)` (as shown above) and before `./program`. Also I tried other syntax like `\0`, `\x0`, `\x00` both quoted with `'` and `"` as well as with and without the `$`. None of those seemed to make any difference…

---

And here I'm out of ideas. I tried few more things but all seemed to run down to the same problems as listed.

**What else could I do? Is it doable at all?**

Sure, I could make the `program` accept the patterns and do searches itself. But it is a lot of double work while fixing it to a specific syntax. (What about providing files by a `grep` for example?).

Also I could make the `program` accept a file with a list of paths. Then I can easily dump `find` expression to some temp file and provide the path to that file only. This could supported be along direct paths so that if user has just a simple path it can be provided without intermediate file. But this doesn't seem nice - one needs to create extra files and take care of them, not to mention extra implementation required. (On the plus side, however, it could be a rescue for cases in which the number of files as arguments start to cause issues with command line length…)

---

At the end, let me remind you again that `find`+`xargs` (and alike) tricks will not work in my case. For description simplicity I'm showing only one argument. But my true case looks more like this:

```
$ ABC_FILES=$(find -L some/dir -name \*.abc | sort)
$ XYZ_FILES=$(find -L other/dir -name \*.xyz | sort)
$ ./program --abc-files $ABC_FILES --xyz-files $XYZ_FILES
```

So doing an `xargs` from one search still leaves me with how to deal with the other one…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use arrays.

If you don't need to handle the possibility of newlines in your filenames, then you could get away with

```
mapfile -t ABC_FILES < <(find -L some/dir -name \*.abc | sort)
mapfile -t XYZ_FILES < <(find -L other/dir -name \*.xyz | sort)
```

then

```
./program --abc-files "${ABC_FILES[@]}" --xyz-files "${XYZ_FILES[@]}"
```

If you **do** need to handle newlines within filenames, and have bash >= 4.4, you can use `-print0` and `-d ''` to null-terminate the names during array construction:

```
mapfile -td '' ABC_FILES < <(find -L some/dir -name \*.abc -print0 | sort -z)
```

(and similarly for the `XYZ_FILES`). If you **don't** have the newer bash, then you could use a null-terminated read loop to append filenames to the arrays e.g.

```
ABC_FILES=()
while IFS= read -rd '' f; do ABC_FILES+=( "$f" ); done < <(find -L some/dir -name \*.abc -print0 | sort -z)
```

Comment: Excellent! I was thinking about arrays. But somehow I didn't found anything on that `mapfile` (or its synonym `readarray`). But it does work!

Comment: Yet you could improve it a bit. The Bash < 4.4 version (which I happen to have...) with a `while` loop doesn't clear the array. Which means that if no files are found the array is undefined. While if it is already defined new files will be appended (instead of replacing the old ones). It seems that adding `declare -a ABC_FILES='()';` before `while` does the trick. (While just adding `ABC_FILES='()';` does not.)

Comment: Also what does the `< <` mean here? Is it the same as `<<`? I don't think so as changing it to `<<` yields syntax error ("unexpected token \`('"). So what it is and how does it work?

Comment: Another improvement (along my particular usage) is to construct yet another array. So we have those `ABC_FILES`. That is fine. But it is useful to also make `ABS_ARGS` which is an empty array if `ABC_FILES` is empty or else it is an array `('--abc-files' "${ABC_FILES[@]}")`. This way later on I can use it like this: `./program "${ABC_ARGS[@]}" "${XYZ_ARGS[@]}"` and be sure that it will work correctly regardless of which (if any) of the groups is empty. Or to state it differently: this way `--abc-files` (and `--xyz-files`) will be provided only if it is followed by some actual path.

Comment: Consider extending your answer based on those comments, so that it is more useful and easily available (not all people read lengthy comments, especially if the answer is just working...). I'm accepting it anyway. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamBadura: `while read ... done < <(find blah)` is normal shell redirection `<` from a special file created by [PROCESS SUBSTITUTION](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution). This differs from piping `find blah | while read ... done` because the pipeline runs the `while` loop in a subshell so the var(s) set in it aren't retained for subsequent commands.

Comment: There is another interesting edge case. With the approach shown above am I able to check if the `<(find ...)` expression failed or not? In some scenarios it will by my own program and if it exists with non-`0` status I would rather interrupt the whole procedure with an error message. While it seems to me that with this approach I will end up with an empty array (as my program doesn't generate any output in such cases).

Answer (score 4):

You can use IFS=newline (assuming no filenames contain newline) but you must set it in the outer shell BEFORE the substitution:

```
$ ls -1
a file with spaces
able
alpha
baker
boo hoo hoo
bravo
$ # note semicolon here; it's not enough to be in the environment passed
$ # to printf, it must be in the environment OF THE SHELL WHILE PARSING
$ IFS=$'\n'; printf '%s\n' --afiles $(find . -name 'a*') --bfiles $(find . -name 'b*')
--afiles
./able
./a file with spaces
./alpha
--bfiles
./bravo
./boo hoo hoo
./baker
```

With `zsh` but not `bash` you can use null `$'\0'` as well. Even in `bash` you could handle newline if there's one sufficiently strange character that is never used like

```
 IFS=$'\1'; ... $(find ... -print0 | tr '\0' '\1') ...
```

However, this approach does not handle the additional request you made in comments on @steeldriver's answer to omit the --afiles if find a is empty.

Comment: So as I understand in Bash there is no way to force `IFS` to split on `null`?

Comment: @AdamBadura: I'm pretty sure not; bash doesn't allow null byte in any variable, including IFS. Note the `read -d ''` used in steeldriver's methods is an _empty_ string not one containing a null byte. (And a command option isn't a var as such anyway.)

Comment: You must also disable globbing (`set -o noglob`) before using that split+glob operator (except in `zsh`).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 [In bash, $'\0' is precisely the same as '': an empty string.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36587726/6843677).

Comment: @AdamBadura Yes, In bash, a null is exactly the same as `$'\0'` and also as `''`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand why you gave up on `xargs`.

> So doing an `xargs` from one search still leaves me with how to deal with the other one…

The string `--xyz-files` is just one of many arguments and there's no reason to consider it special before it is interpreted by your program. I think you can pass it through `xargs` among both `find` results:

```
{ find -L some/dir -name \*.abc -print0 | sort -z; echo -ne "--xyz-files\0"; find -L other/dir -name \*.xyz -print0 | sort -z; } | xargs -0 ./program --abc-files
```

Comment: You are right! This works as well! However notice that you missed `-print0` in second `find`. Also if going this way I would put the `--abc-files` as an `echo` as well - just for consistency.

Comment: This approach seems simpler and somewhat more one-liner than the array approach. However it would require some extra logic to cover case that if there are no `.abc` files then there should also be no `--abc-files` (same with `.xyz`). The [array-based solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318429/101845) by [steeldriver](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) also requires extra logic for it but that logic is trivial there while it might be not-so-trivial here destroying the main advantage of this solution - simplicity.

Comment: Also I'm not really sure but I assume that `xargs` will never try to split arguments and make few commands instead of one, *unless* it is *explicitly* instructed to do so with `-L`, `--max-lines` (`-l`), `--max-args` (`-n`) or `--max-chars` (`-s`) arguments. Am I right? Or are there some defaults? As my program would not handle such split correctly and I would rather have a failure to call it...

Comment: @AdamBadura Missing `-print0` -- fixed, thanks. I don't know all the answers but I agree my solution makes it hard to include extra logic. I would probably go with arrays myself, now when I know this approach. My answer was not really for you. You had already accepted the other answer and I assumed your problem is solved. I just wanted to point out you can pass arguments from multiple sources through `xargs`, which wasn't obvious at first glance. You may treat it as a proof of concept. Now we all know few different approaches and we can consciously choose what fits us in every particular case.

Comment: Yes, I already implemented the array-based solution and it works like charm. I'm especially proud of how cleanly it deals with the optionality (if no files then no `--abc-files`). But you are right - it is good to know your alternatives! Especially that I mistakenly thought it is not possible.